# masking in openCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, computer-vision

Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1)

this piece of code is supposed to create a mask, I think, by using C++. What is the equivalent to creating a mask in C, like this? also, can someone explain to me what this piece of code is actually doing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the C API, we would call

```
IplImage *mask = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvSetZero(mask);
```

The C API is easier to read IMO, and what it does is create an image with 8 bits per pixel, 1 channel (grayscale), of the same size as `img1`, and then setting all its pixel values to zero.

Comment: Mr. Audet, I have to extract a human body from an image. I have used cvContours to see all the contours and the human has the largest contour. However, I do not know how to apply cvContourArea to find the area and use the largest area value in order to extract the human body. it is a motion recognition project showing someone walking. Would you mind taking a look at my code and telling me what I need to put in? I really need help to finish this as the deadline is fast approaching but I'm only getting stuck. Please help

Comment: There is a sample showing how to loop over the contours at the [cvDrawContours()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_drawing_functions.html#drawcontours) entry of the manual. So just copy/paste that and call `cvContourArea()` on each contour instead of `cvDrawContours()`. But I doubt if this is enough to solve your problem. Computer vision is a very challenging field.